# How to change a constant's value in perl

Tags: perl

```
our $TEST;
*TEST = \100;
$TEST =200
```

I want to change `TEST`'s value to `200` for specific reasons. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: Why do you want to change constants?

Comment: Need to override in some point

Comment: @Andy => the `*TEST = \100` syntax creates an alias to a constant value that will cause perl to blow up if you try to write to it.  It of course won't be inlined like a constant subroutine though.

Comment: I am also confused here. This isn't a constant. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same syntax : `*TEST = \200`
BTW, you may want to look at [`Const::Fast`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Const%3a%3aFast).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this statement:

```
local $TEST = 200;
```

Comment: +1 for the `local`.  I might write `local *TEST = \200` though, to preserve the "constant" nature

Answer (score 0):

If you do use constansts  and then use a constant value, then before messing around with it remember that Perl normally optimizes away constant code - i.e. maybe skipping an if condition which said - if (DEBUG) or hard coding a value (e.g. PI) during its intermediate byte code generation. [constant pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the write way to do a constant in perl. The right way is

```
use constant TEST => 100;
```

Now if that's declared in a module, and you want to change that value from a test you can put

```
use unconstant;
```

At the top, and then you can follow that up with another declaration.

```
use unconstant;
use MyLib;
use constant *MyLib::TEST => 200;
```

---

*I am the author of `unconstant`*